# Convert HMAC-SHA1 PHP script to C# script

Tags: c#, php, hmacsha1

I am working on a project to consume an API and I need to generate a signature for the web service call header. The API documentation provides some PHP sample code with a "known good" result so you can convert it to your programming language of choice and I've run into a wall and I need some help.

I've never worked with HMAC before so this is very new to me and I would appreciate ANY feedback provided.

Basically the API provided a sample PHP script and it's results so that you can write your version of it and test it out.

Here's the PHP sample and its result. I will post my current C# attempt at the same code below that. Again, THANK YOU in advance for any help you can provide.

```
    Use the following code example to compare your signature generation with a
    known signature. The PHP code example that follows provides a reference to
    the generation of a signature for a GET call into the CDRN API. Use your
    code with the parameter values listed to validate the same signature is
    generated.

    <?php
    $cdrn_domain = "api.testing.cdrn.com";
    $secret_key = "cdrnpassword";
    $api_version = "1.1";
    $method_type = "GET";
    $case_id = "12345";
    $string_date = "2014-06-20T12:06:31Z";
    $string_to_sign = $method_type . "\n" . $cdrn_domain . "\n" . "/partners/cases/$case_id" . "\n" . "" . "\n" . $api_version . "\n" . $string_date . "\n";

    $signature = utf8_encode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $string_to_sign, $secret_key, false)));
    echo "SIGNATURE[$signature]";
    ?>
```

Output:
        SIGNATURE[NWY3N2Q0NTdmZDQxZjA4YWI0Njg3YTEwODljODdiNTEwMTdmMzNlZg==]

Here is the C# code I need help with:

```
    using System.Security.Cryptography;

    string cdrn_domain = "api.testing.cdrn.com";
    string secret_key = "cdrnpassword";
    string api_version = "1.1";
    string method_type = "GET";
    string case_id = "12345";
    string string_date = "2014-06-20T12:06:31Z";
    string string_to_sign = method_type + "\n" + cdrn_domain + "\n" + "/partners/cases/" + case_id + "\n" + "" + "\n" + api_version + "\n" + string_date + "\n";

    var result = CreateSignature(string_to_sign, secret_key);

    public string CreateSignature(string message, string key)
    {
        var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(key);
        byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
        using (var hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(keyByte, false))
        {
            byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha1.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
        }
    }
```

The Signature generated from MY C# Code is: 
X3fUV/1B8Iq0aHoQich7UQF/M+8=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is because you (*or the API*) were encoding the *wrong* hash value.

From the PHP documentation for [`hash_hmac`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php):

> `string hash_hmac ( string $algo , string $data , string $key [, bool $raw_output = false ] )`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> ...
>
> **raw_output**
>
> When set to **TRUE**, outputs raw binary data. **FALSE** outputs lowercase hexits.

So the line:

```
$signature = utf8_encode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $string_to_sign, $secret_key, false)));
```

instead of producing the base64-encoded HMAC hash value, it actually produces a... **base64-encoded string of lowercased-hex value of the HMAC hash** itself ... in UTF-8...  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

You should notice that by replacing the third parameter of `hash_mac` from `false` to `true`, it would actually produce the same value as your C# function.

```
$signature = utf8_encode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $string_to_sign, $secret_key, true)));
```

demo: [ideone.com/lyrgKV](http://ideone.com/lyrgKV)

---

Obviously, to fix things from your side (C#) to match the API output, we need to lowercase-hex the hash before encoding it to base64:

```
public static string CreateSignature(string message, string key)
{
    var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(key);
    byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
    using (var hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(keyByte, false))
    {
        byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha1.ComputeHash(messageBytes);

        string hashstring = BitConverter.ToString(hmacsha1.ComputeHash(messageBytes)).Replace("-","").ToLower();

        return Convert.ToBase64String(encoding.GetBytes(hashstring));
    }
}
```

demo: [dotnetfiddle.net/FT4OQ4](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FT4OQ4)

Comment: IronGeek, I would have never figured this out without your help sir! Thank you so much for the explanation and the quick assist! Accepting your answer right away!!!